# Open settings in iphone manually

Tags: iphone, ios7

Is there any way to open Settings in iOS7 manually ?

i am using UIActivityViewController for providing various sharing options, now problem is if user is not already logged in either in Facebook or Twitter then I need to redirect the user to settings screen and let them configure their accounts from there itself, i have no idea that how to open Settings screen manually, If there is any way to do that then please let me know Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean open Settings by Custom URL scheme?

Comment: At any way i need to open settings screen @ShivanRaptor

Comment: No, you can't. No public API to do so. You can write instructions for your users.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you handle the situation when user is not logged in and they need to configure his/her account ? @ShivanRaptor

Comment: Just ask them to go to "Settings" App by text, maybe graphics.

Comment: You can only open app listed here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 5.1, there is no official way to open Settings via App.